# Webcam not working on Sony vaio pro 13 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, webcam, vaio, sony

Yesterday i installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my brand new sony vaio pro 13,
You can find the specifications [here](http://svparch.blogspot.mx/2013/09/arch-linux-installation-on-sony-vaio.html).

Apparently no one had issues with the webcam before when using 13.10 or 13.04. So, as a new ubuntu user i would like to know how to solve this problem.

**Update**

lsusb result

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b42a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0eef:a108 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci result

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

Comment: down vote
 

I got the same issue and have reported it as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1305306

Please add yourself as affected to add some heat.

I've also noticed that the cam works in Skype, but not in any other application. Cheese shows the image for like a second; Hangouts is completely distorted with static and stuff.

Comment: @DanielHolm I added myself. The cam does not work with Skype for me though, it's how i discovered the bug.

Comment: Could you do a "lsusb" and a "lspci" in a terminal and post the result?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Aha, it's not the exact same device. Perhaps yours is newer. I suggest you submit a new bug report to launchpad. Run "ubuntu-bug linux" from command line or unity.